# Filtering result using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array, but am having issues with returning only the values which are true (status: yes).

```
 var arr = {
     "status": "Yes"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  }


  var filteredResult = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].status == "Yes") {
    filteredResult.push(status);
  }
}

console.log (filteredResult);
```

I am still learning JS, but I hope to improve.
Thank you.

Comment: `status`  should be `arr[i]`.

Comment: There is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this code compiles - you need to include square brackets to declare an array.

```
const arr = 
  [{ "status": "Yes" },
  { "status": "No" },
  { "status": "No" },
  { "status": "No" }]
```

Then to filter it, just do

```
const results = arr.filter((item) => { return item.status === "Yes" })
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great, and an arrow function too. Which I have only just started learning about.

Comment: or more short : arr.filter( i => i.status === "Yes" )

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong so for loop won't work. The array should be inside "[]". Refer to the below code. I have tested and is working fine.

If you want to get list of all object having status "Yes", then use filteredResult.push(arr[i]), else filteredResult.push(arr[i].status) if you need strings of "Yes"

```js
var arr = [{
     "status": "Yes"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  },
  {
      "status": "No"
  }]


  var filteredResult = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].status == "Yes") {
        filteredResult.push(arr[i]);
      }
  }
```